# Unity2D: How to interpret stack trace output for 'Leak Detected: Persistent allocates 2 individual allocations' error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I am working in a unity2d project and have recently noticed this error appearing at the start of the game. I have looked around to try and determine the cause, but have been so far unsuccessful.

`Leak Detected: Persistant allocates 2 individual allocations. To find out more please enable 'Jobs/LeakDetection/Full StackTraces' and reproduce the leak again.`

I went to project settings > Player > Stack Traces, and switched all the options to full. When I re-played the scene, I got a more verbose output from unity. I attempted to read through it, but I do not understand how to determine the issue. Any direction on what caused this leak would be more than helpful, and I can share more info if needed.

[Enabled stack traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxKak.png)

[Output after enabling stack traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgSwW.png)

[Player Log](https://pastebin.com/vTyJ0RhB)

Unity Version: 2023.1.0 (beta)
OS: Win 11 Pro

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code or reproduction steps, it's hard to tell. Some bugs with long exception stack traces are generated even by clicking around in the Editor and are just bugs (which, fair enough, need to be reported).

Unity 2023 is on the `Prerelease Technology` stream. This is unreliable and contains a lot of bugs and it will tkae approximately a year before it becomes stable enough to become the `Tech Stream` (also moving 2022 to the LTS and deprecating Unity 2020 and Unity 2021).

Any code you develop in it is **not** ready for production and this stream is not recommended for finished projects. I can tell you just in 2 months I found 6 bugs, 3 of them being breaking bugs in the UnityEditor (true, they were fixed, but you get the idea), one was a bug by just innocently clicking on an empty space in the Inspector after selecting some Canvas flags which made the Inspector unusable (fixed now). The point of the `PT Stream` is to find as many bugs as possible to work into making it as stable as possible and ready for the `TS`, while also providing new tools, user requests, engine features and newer technologies.

Having said that, if you *do* want to try Unity 2023, the latest version on the `PT Stream` is Unity 2023.2.0a15 at the time of this writing. Unity Technologies releases a new update every week (the next one should be here around May 24 or 25). A slightly more stable release is the Beta, but not by much.

If you want to work on a project, either go for `LTS` or `TS`. While Unity Technologies still has *some* support for Unity 2020, Unity 2021 is the recommended LTS go-to version. Personally, I recommend you skip it and move directly to TS and use Unity 2022. It will become the next LTS "soon" (no LTS deprecation news for 2020 and 2021 yet).

TLDR: Either install Unity 2023.2.x**a**y (the alpha build) to get the latest build (which has the most features and fixes), either settle on the latest 2023.1.x**b**y (the beta build) for stability. For example, I see you use the first 2023 version of the 9th beta build which is quite old, considering the latest beta build is 17 now. I recommend you stick to Unity 2022 (yes, 2022, not 2023) and see if the problem persists.

If the problem still persists, use `Help -> Report a bug.` You can describe all reproduction steps there, attach the call stack (which you can copy from the console onto a `.txt` file) and the project will automatically be included in the report. Keep in mind, their policy is for you to generally report bugs on the latest version, since some of them would most likely be fixed. Unity support is very quick to handle bug reports, even for free licenses. You'll always get a mail for each step they take, so you will always see the progress of your report in real-time with access to the public bugtracker. And don't worry if you think you're project will be posted all over the Internet. Attachments are only visible to Unity employees and only you can see your own bug posts (unless something changed in the meantime). So privacy is ensured, including for your project. Still my advice is to reproduce the bug and report it on a draft project instead of sending them a 900 MB project (unless you can't reproduce it outside your own project).

P.S. as advice, clean up the personal info on the logs before posting them on StackOverflow. I can see your usename, internal and external IPs.